# Check if table exists, if not do nothing

Tags: sas

I have a problem with my macro. Try to create a table if the name exists.

```
%let tableA = Cars;
%let tableB =;
```

This works:

```
%macro CREATETABLE(name); 
%if %symexist(name) = 1 %then %do; 
proc sql;
Create table ....
```

But if the table name doesnt exists:

```
%else...( do nothing )
```

i want SAS to do **nothing**, but i didnt get it to work. Getting always SAS errors because the table name doenst exists.

```
%CREATETABLE(CARS)/%CREATETABLE(&tableA) - works, %symexist(chkTabelle) -> 1
%CREATETABEL(asfsf)/%CREATETABLE(&tableB) - error, %symexist(chkTabelle) -> 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%symexist checks to see if a macro symbol exists. The macro symbol NAME always exists. It sounds like you want to check if a dataset exists. To do that, you use the EXIST() function.

From the docs:

http://support.sas.com/kb/24/670.html

```
%macro checkds(dsn);
   %if %sysfunc(exist(&dsn)) %then %do;
      proc print data = &dsn;
      run;
   %end;
   %else %do;
      data _null_;
         file print;
         put #3 @10 "Data set &dsn. does not exist";
      run;
   %end;
%mend checkds;
```